# How can I get email and full name from Firebase Apple sign-in?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, apple-sign-in

With the latest update Firebase let you sign in with `AppleAuthProvider` without using the `sign_in_with_apple` package. This is really useful but how can I get the full name and email of the user?

I know that I can add scopes with the function `.addScope()` but then how can I retrieve them?

Just to make an example now we can retrieve those data with the following procedure:

```dart
final AuthorizationCredentialAppleID credential =
   await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
    scopes: <AppleIDAuthorizationScopes>[
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
    ],
   nonce: nonce,
);
final String name = credential.givenName + credential.familyName;
final String email = credential.email;
```

But now I'd like to something like this

```dart
final AppleAuthProvider appleAuth = AppleAuthProvider();
appleAuth.addScope('email');
appleAuth.addScope('name');

final UserCredential authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithAuthProvider(appleAuth);
final String name = ... //What should I put here?
```

Comment: I got the same problem with apple sign in with firebase on Android.
Did you manage to get something other than the displayName ?
Like a family name and a given name ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to reference the email or name? I've done the remove app from appleID so it is reset, but even adding scopes for email and name, they are not included on the returned user object, so i'm not sure where to find them?

Comment: I dropped the whole thing some months ago. The only things that I can say are: you can still get those data by using the official package of AppleLogin and using with Firebase, but I also noticed that they resolved this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9662#issuecomment-1416488818) some hours ago

Answer (score 3):

It Looks like it is a bug
[Github issue reported](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9662)

Hope they fix it as soon as possible

**EDIT************

I found out that this could happen because the first time you used this method, you didn't use scope.

The solution is to go to **Settings> iCloud> Password and security> Apps that use the Apple ID**.
And delete your app, since Apple only the first time you use the method, is when it brings the information you request

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33576024)